# Python Numpy intersect1d on 1D array with 2D array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to use the intersect1d function with a view on a 2D array to find the intersection of it's first column with another 1D array, maintaining its 2nd column in the end result. However I'm stuck trying to construct the view.

Example input:

```
a1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[4,9]], dtype=np.uint32)
a2 = np.array([8,3,8,1,0,9,3,2], dtype=np.uint32)
```

The desired result is:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Comment: The documentation of [np.intersect1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) does not tell anything about multidimensional arrays (although it still returns a result, without raising any error or depreciation warnings...). However this is not the result you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you would like to have the rows indices or a mask of intersecting ones. Now [`np.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) won't actually give you either. To solve it, you can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to get the mask of intersecting  rows. Thus, indexing with it would be your desired output, like so -

```
a1[np.in1d(a1[:,0],a2)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: a1
Out[15]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 9]], dtype=uint32)

In [16]: a2
Out[16]: array([8, 3, 8, 1, 0, 9, 3, 2], dtype=uint32)

In [17]: np.in1d(a1[:,0],a2) # Intersecting rows mask for a1
Out[17]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [18]: a1[np.in1d(a1[:,0],a2)]
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=uint32)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. This gives me the following error on a bigger dataset: IndexError: too many indices

Comment: @tdma So, in your bigger case - Is `a1` a 2D array and `a2` a 1D array?

Comment: Affirmative, exactly the same structure just more rows (or pairs if you want) in a1. It starts failing after about 1 million pairs/rows in a1.

Comment: @tdma Well that sounds puzzling to me as well. It could complain about memory error for really huge datasets, but that indexing error doesn't make sense to me. Also, please make sure the datatype of these arrays are not Object.

Comment: Solved, didn't know that .append flattens the array by default.